# How to select your start kingdom in KoA?

Tags: king-of-avalon-dragon-warfare

When starting a game, usually the kingdom in the game is assigned randomly on the start. Is there any way to select in which kingdom you'd like to start your castle? For clarification, please check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2PTye4WeELI) demonstrating different kingdoms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to change your kingdom within first 5 days if your stronghold level is less than 6. To do that, find selected kingdom on the map, then click on the location of your interest (somewhere on grassland), you should see *Join Kingdom* option. After stronghold level is 6 and above, it's not possible to change the kingdom (only at the Excalibur event, then you can only invade another kingdoms).